# Loop overdub bar

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I have a question about loop overdubbing: 
Let's say I record with my looper a simple 2-bar melody or whatever, like:

[image]

then, using the same pedal to overdub it, I record something that is one bar long like:

[image]

what will happen? I mean,will the first 2 bars (first recording) play and at the beginning of each bar,the second recording will play?

Or will it just play at the first of the first bar and then the 3rd etc.. ?

Comment: Simple thing to do is try it !! It can always be deleted, and you'll have your answer either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your first bar is 4 seconds long, so the first recording then becomes 8 secs. The overdub is only 4 secs long, so will only replay alongside the first 4 secs. (1st bar).The second bar remains as original.

They are great fun, and a good tool to have.Make your own backing track in a few minutes, add bass, whatever, and play lead along to yourself.Scrub any mistakes immediately. If you can afford it, go for a twin pedal model, which will give the opportunity to replay different mixes. There's also a quite expensive multi-pedal model.

Comment: I didn't understand the `The second bar remains as original.` part. 

I was thinking of buying the Ditto Looper from TC electronic

Comment: The second bar will just play as is, unless you overdub something during the second bar's time.This site is not for recommending gear, however, I do like my Boss RC-30.

Answer (score 9):

Most simple loop pedals don't know about bars - it's just a sound sample of a length you set.

Typically:

- You start recording by tapping a pedal
- You play your instrument
- You mark the end of the loop by tapping the pedal. The length of the loop is now set.
- The loop keeps playing, over and over.
- When you overdub, you add sounds to the loop

More advanced loopers with more complicated interfaces allow you to have multiple loops of different lengths. For example with the iOS app "Loopy", you can have several independent loops, with lengths that are whole-number multiples of the base loop, or even completely unsynchronised.

Answer (score 0):

You need a multitrack looper with multi-sync feature (whatever the name).

I know three of them : 
- Boomerang III
- Pigtronix Infinity Looper
- Boss RC300 (just guess, for the price...)

In this looper, you can define the shorter loop (n bars) then, let say the second track is defined as 3x as long as the first track, play the longer loop on 3n bars. The 2 tracks will be synchronized.